# Chess.js does not detect stalemate

Tags: chess, chessboard.js, fen

For the given fen string -

k7/1R1RN3/p3p3/P3P2p/1PP4P/3K1PP1/8/8 b KQkq h3 0 1

Chess.js does not detect and show chess.moves() gives you ['0-0-0'], which is queen side castling, Not possible without a queen.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe queen side castling without a queen is a code for stalemate? :)

Comment: Haha, I guess, then .in_stalemate() or .in_draw() should return true,

Comment: "Queen side castling" is a move involving king and rook, it is quite possible without a queen

Comment: Can you please check the fen string and see why is it not being detected?

Comment: @HardeepMehta the fen string is OK, if you have described the situation accurately then it would be a bug in "chess.js"

Comment: consider posting on chess.stackexchange.com instead , as posted this is not really a question for StackOverflow.  If you want to report a bug in some library then use their support channel.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a problem with the fen string, The castling flags were not set right!

The fen should be :

k7/1R1RN3/p3p3/P3P2p/1PP4P/3K1PP1/8/8 b - h3 0 1